# MVC Multitenant Application Instance Scope on Context using Autofac?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, autofac, multi-tenant

Hi everyone I am optimizing my Application and have a Question about it. I have a Design that looks like this:

ApplicationCore -> T4 from ApplicationDatabases Model Generator

ApplicationData -> Respositories which Access the Database Context in ApplicationCore

```
    public class entityRepository<TEntity> : entityRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
    protected readonly DatabaseContext dbContext;
    protected readonly IDbSet<TEntity> currentTableContext;

    public entityRepository(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        this.DbContext = context;
        currentTableContext = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
```

ApplicationDatabases -> Database created from Model Generator

ApplicationServices -> Services that creates a entityRepository

```
private readonly entityRepository<Users> _userRepository;

public userService(entityRepository<Users> userRepository)
{
     _userRepository = userRepository;
}
```

What I would like to know if I am allowed to Register the entityRepository as InstancePerTenant in Autofac or should I use another Instance Scope.

```
builder.Register(context => new DatabaseContext()).InstancePerTenant();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(entityRepository<>)).As(typeof(IentityRepository<>)).InstancePerTenant;
```

I am doing that at the moment and it works but I am not sure If I would get any Resources or similiar Problems later. I would also be happy if I get some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, I have worked in a project that is multi-tenant, but does not use autofac. I have few points to put forth to you for a discussion

1. In case of a multi-tenant application and having the user and entity repositories loaded on memory for each tenant, seems like a bit of overhead
2. In case of a use case wherein a tenant wishes to view his child tenant's data, how can this be achieved
3. When there is an application load of 50 tenant's what happens to the parallelism and responsiveness to the load from the application point of view.

Kindly think through these use cases and the others that might come up after moving to production and share your thoughts.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider the suggestions and it helped me a lot! :)